# Как отключить опеределенный поиск в колекции mongodb, если значние равно null?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Здравствуйте. На сайте есть форма поиска, и если поле не заполенно я передаю в объект поиска значне *null*.
На сервере должен идти поиск по указанным критериям, но как отменить поиск определенного ключа если оно равно null?
Пример создаия объекта поиска:

```js
searchArray = [form.elements.ageFor.value || null, 
                         form.elements.ageTo.value || null,
                         form.elements.country.value || null,
                         form.elements.city.value || null,
                         form.elements.topics.value || null
                        ];
function CreateSearthObject() {
    this.ageFor = searchArray[0];
    this.ageTo = searchArray[1];
    this.male = userMale || null;
    this.country = searchArray[2];
    this.city = searchArray[3];
    this.topics = searchArray[4];
}
```

Потом это уже летит на сервер и там:

```js
socket.on('search', function(requestID, searchData){
        db.collection('users').find(age: {$gte : searchData.age, $lte : searchData.age}).toArray(function(error, docs){
            io.emit('displayAllUsers', docs, requestedID);
        });
//Как в find отключить поиск по age если в searchData оно равно null?
```

Comment: Использовать `undefined` вместо него?

Comment: @Qwertiy, разве тогда не будет сравнивать age с undefined? точнеё там стоит фильтр та больше или равно и меньше или равно отпределенного возраста

Comment: Так надо всё поле убирать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ age: searchData.age ? {$gte: searchData.age, $lte: searchData.age} : undefined }
```

Comment: идет ошибка db.collection('users').find(age: searchData.age ? {$gte: searchData.age, $lte: searchData.age} : undefined).toArray(function(error, docs){
                                    ^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: @Horchynskyi, ну фигурные скобки-то кто за тебя ставить будет? Это же объект. Я ж только одно поле скопировал.

Comment: undefined выводит на docs в консоли

Comment: а нет работает, правда только с возрастом ОТ, но наверное это я криво подключил второй параметр ДО

Answer (score 0):

```
socket.on('search', function(requestID, searchData){
   var query = {};
   if (searchData.age) {
       query.age = {"$gte" : searchData.age, "$lte" : searchData.age}
   } else {
       query = {}
   }
    db.collection('users').find(query).toArray(function(error, docs){
        io.emit('displayAllUsers', docs, requestedID);
    });
```

Вот самый простой вариант, конечно лучше сделать какую-то функцию, которая будет билдить запросы в зависимости от параметров.

Comment: Эм.. Зачем вообще age в else?

Comment: а, точн, не просек, что у него везде age

Comment: Вообще else убери, а то так будет только для одного поискового параметра работать.

Comment: Это всего лишь пример с пояснениями, я посоветовал написать функцию, которая будет билдить запросы